# Transformar un arreglo para resumir datos en javascript

Tags: javascript, array, reduce

Estoy trabajando con una base de trabajos que se registran diariamente, y necesito resumir la información agrupando por empresa y obtener la suma de avance de cada faena.

Un ejemplo de los registros:

```
let trabajos = [{
    faena: 'Mantención AAVC',
    avance: 235,
    medida: 'Metros',
    empresa: 'Empresa Uno'
},
{
    faena: 'Mantención AAVC',
    avance: 125,
    medida: 'Metros',
    empresa: 'Empresa Uno'
},
{
    faena: 'Mantención AAVC',
    avance: 100,
    medida: 'Metros',
    empresa: 'Empresa Dos'
},
{
    faena: 'Mantención Caminos',
    avance: 2,
    medida: 'Km',
    empresa: 'Empresa Dos'
},
{
    faena: 'Poda',
    avance: 600,
    medida: 'Metros',
    empresa: 'Empresa Dos'
}]
```

Lo que busco como resultados sería algo así:

```
resumen = [{
    empresa: 'Empresa Uno',
    trabajos: [
        {
            faena: 'Mantención AAVC',
            avance: 360,
            medida: 'Metros',
        }
    ]
},
{
    empresa: 'Empresa Dos',
    trabajos: [
        {
            faena: 'Mantención AAVC',
            avance: 100,
            medida: 'Metros'
        },
        {
            faena: 'Mantención Caminos',
            avance: 2,
            medida: 'Km'
        },
        {
            faena: 'Poda',
            avance: 600,
            medida: 'Metros'
        }
    ]
}]
```

Intenté con reduce() y filter() pero obtengo un arreglo con las distintas empresas y una lista de trabajos de la misma, y me enredé en como puedo resumir la información para obtener cada faena con la sumatoria de ellas por empresa.

```
const resp = trabajos.reduce((arrayTrabajo, trabajo) => {
const found = arrayTrabajo.find(a => a.empresa === trabajo.empresa);
const value = trabajo; 
if (!found) {
    arrayTrabajo.push({ empresa: trabajo.empresa, trabajos: [value] }); 
}
else {
    found.trabajos.push(value); 
}
return arrayTrabajo; }, []);  console.log(resp);
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Con `reduce()` y `find()` lo puedes conseguir.

Necesitas encontrar primero la empresa en el acumulador, si existe, entonces tienes que encontrar al faena en la lista de trabajos de esa empresa, y entonces ahí añadir el avance.

Si no existe la faena, entonces tienes que añadir una faena nueva a la lista de trabajos de la empresa.

Si no existe la empresa, entonces tienes que crear la empresa con una lista de trabajos con el trabajo nuevo.

```js
const trabajos = [{
    faena: 'Mantención AAVC',
    avance: 235,
    medida: 'Metros',
    empresa: 'Empresa Uno'
},
{
    faena: 'Mantención AAVC',
    avance: 125,
    medida: 'Metros',
    empresa: 'Empresa Uno'
},
{
    faena: 'Mantención AAVC',
    avance: 100,
    medida: 'Metros',
    empresa: 'Empresa Dos'
},
{
    faena: 'Mantención Caminos',
    avance: 2,
    medida: 'Km',
    empresa: 'Empresa Dos'
},
{
    faena: 'Poda',
    avance: 600,
    medida: 'Metros',
    empresa: 'Empresa Dos'
}];

const resumen = trabajos.reduce((acumulador, trabajo) => {
  // Recuperar la empresa del acumulador.
  const empresaEnAcumulador = acumulador.find(({ empresa }) => empresa === trabajo.empresa);

  if (empresaEnAcumulador) {
    // Recuperar la faena de la empresa del acumulador.
    const faenaEnEmpresa = empresaEnAcumulador.trabajos.find(({ faena }) => faena === trabajo.faena);

    if (faenaEnEmpresa) {
      // Añadir el avance a la faena de la empresa del acumulador.
      faenaEnEmpresa.avance += trabajo.avance;
    }
    else {
      // La faena no existe en la empresa del acumulador, la añadimos.
      const nuevoTrabajo = { faena: trabajo.faena, avance: trabajo.avance, medida: trabajo.medida };

      empresaEnAcumulador.trabajos.push(nuevoTrabajo);
    }
  }
  else {
    // La empresa no existe en el acumulador, así que la añadimos.
    acumulador.push({ empresa: trabajo.empresa, trabajos: [ { faena: trabajo.faena, avance: trabajo.avance, medida: trabajo.medida } ]});
  }

  return acumulador;
}, []);

console.log(resumen);
```